# Understanding Exception tests in JUnit 5

Tags: java, exception, junit5

I've been away from Java for a while and JUnit 5 has come along in the meantime. I'm trying to rewrite some existing JUnit 4 tests as JUnit 5 but I'm struggling with how to handle methods that throw exceptions. For example, I have a class I wrote called LocalizationUtils (not to be confused with any other class by that name found in the API) and it has a method called getResources() which wants a non-null base name as an input and returns the corresponding resource bundle if it can be found. It throws a NullPointerException if the base name is null and a MissingResourceException if the resource bundle can't be located. Here's the code:

```
    static public ResourceBundle getResources(String baseName) throws NullPointerException, MissingResourceException {

    if (baseName == null) {
        final String msg = "The base name cannot be null.";
        NullPointerException npExcp = new NullPointerException(msg); 
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, msg, npExcp);
        throw npExcp;
        }

    /* Get the resource bundle for the current locale. */
    try {
        return(ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName));
        } 
    catch (MissingResourceException mrExcp) {
        String msg = "Unable to find resources for base name " + baseName + "."; 
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, msg, mrExcp); 
        throw mrExcp;
        }

}
```

The manual for JUnit 5 gives this example of handling an exception:

```
@Test
void exceptionTesting() {
    Throwable exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("a message");
    });
    assertEquals("a message", exception.getMessage());
}
```

This example makes no sense to me. It seems to be creating an exception with the message "a message" out of thin air. I don't see that it is actually executing ANY class or method at all. There's no real explanation of how this is supposed to work so maybe/probably it's just a misunderstanding on my part.

In an attempt to write a test that actually executes my code and forces both errors to occur, I wrote this JUnit 5 test:

```
@Test
void testGetResourcesString() {

    //Normal cases

    //Exception - input parameter is null
    /* Verify that the expected type of exception was thrown. */
    Throwable npExcp = assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> {
        LocalizationUtils.getResources(null);
    });   
    /* Verify that the exact right error message was generated. */   
    assertEquals("The base name cannot be null.", npExcp.getMessage()); 


    //Exception - all input is non-null but resource bundle not found
    /* Verify that the expected type of exception was thrown. */
    Throwable mrExcp = assertThrows(MissingResourceException.class, () -> {
        LocalizationUtils.getResources("foo");
    });   
    /* Verify that the exact right error message was generated. */
    assertEquals("Can't find bundle for base name foo, locale en_CA", mrExcp.getMessage());     
}
```

Everything in this test works as I would expect and it seems more logical than the example in the manual since it actually executes a class and method to cause the exception to be thrown. I also wanted to be sure that exactly the right message was generated since it's easy to imagine a method with several input parameters instead of just one where *any* of the parameters being null should throw an exception with a unique message. Simply determining that the right exception was thrown doesn't seem like enough to me: I feel that I want to be sure that the right message was created so that I know the code is reacting to the right null parameter out of several.

I'm reluctant to believe the manual is wrong though; I imagine a team of several experienced developers wrote it and were very careful. Can anyone with more JUnit 5 knowledge than me - which must be just about everyone who has ever used JUnit 5 - confirm that the example in the manual is correct and, if it is, how it is supposed to work when no class or method name is provided?

Comment: You are correct about creating an exception out of thin air. It is equivalent of having `expected = IllegalArgumentException`  and throwing `IllegalArgumentException` in the test method. The only difference is, that the assertions allow you to check for the exception messages directly (unlike JUnit4, where you had to create a `@Rule`)

Comment: Is my JUnit test code a fair and adequate test of my getResource() method in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, you are testing it correctly

Comment: Your use of `assertThrows()` is correct! And I apologize for the unrealistic examples in the User Guide. I've opened a [new issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1651) to address this shortcoming.

Comment: @Sam Brannen - Thank you for confirming that I had the correct understanding of how to use assertThrows(). I was pretty sure I was on the right track but confirmation is always good. And thank you VERY MUCH for taking steps to actually improve the documentation! Way too often, I find shortcomings in documentation and have no idea how to suggest improvements. (The cynical part of me wonders if there's any point even if I can determine the how.) May I suggest one further improvement? I'm using Eclipse 2018-2019 and it has no provision for JUnit5 Test Suites yet - and apparently no intention....

Comment: @Sam Brannen - of providing for them in the near future. (JUnit5 Test CASES work fine; it's just Suites that are missing.) Therefore, a full example a JUnit 5 Test Suite that I could hand-code would be great! (The examples in the JUnit 5 User Guide do NOT work; I believe the runners they use are for JUnit 3 or 4).

Comment: The suite examples in the User Guide do work when running directly JUnit 4, but there is currently no support for suites directly on the JUnit Platform. However, we are planning on adding support for suites in the JUnit Platform. See the [suites](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22theme%3A+suites%22) label on GitHub for details.

Comment: @SamBrannen - Even after reading the linked information, I'm not sure what you're saying. I realize some suite-related code is in development and that's great. But it may be months/years before it's working and available. I'm wondering how I can execute some single thing that understands that I want to run a specified lists of JUnit 5 test cases. I've accumulated several tests now with several more to come and it's getting tedious to have to launch each independently and this will only get worse as the number of tests increases. Is there any code I can write NOW to automate running multiple...

Comment: @SamBrannen - cont'd - tests in one go? That will tide me over until the proposed code is available. :-)

Comment: Since your questions are off-topic, I recommend you either open a new question on Stack Overflow or ask on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/junit-team/junit5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example does call a "method". The lambda expression `() -> {...}` defines an *anonymous method*. It contains one statement: `throw new IllegalArgumentException`.

[Refer to the java language specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

```
() -> {}                // No parameters; result is void
() -> 42                // No parameters, expression body
() -> null              // No parameters, expression body
() -> { return 42; }    // No parameters, block body with return
() -> { System.gc(); }  // No parameters, void block body
(int x) -> x+1              // Single declared-type parameter
(int x) -> { return x+1; }  // Single declared-type parameter
(x) -> x+1                  // Single inferred-type parameter
 x  -> x+1                  // Parens optional for single inferred-type case
```

So the example has one method, and all it does is throw an exception.

```
() -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("a message"); }
```

And in *your* code, you're actually defining one method with no parameters, calling your method with one parameter.

```
() -> { LocalizationUtils.getResources(null); }
```

Comment: Okay, my wording was not as accurate as it should have been: the lambda expression is not quite "thin air" as I described it. But I think my basic point *was* still accurate: the code in the example doesn't test any external class and method, which is what actually gets done in a JUnit test. That's the whole point of JUnit: testing external classes and methods. And it can't test an external class and method if it doesn't ever execute the external class and method. I think you would agree. So is the way I wrote my tests a valid test?

Comment: Well, the point of a unit test is to assert that whatever you call produces the output that you'd expect. Whether you want to stick an external class and call its method in there, or if you just want to check how certain code behaves in Java, is up to you. In this case, they're providing an example of testing *a method* containing one statement (which so happens to be a `throw` statement), and shows what will happen to it. You can expect if you put a class method that throws an Exception, that it will behave similarly (which you have done, with a valid test :) ).